# Trying to match this regex

Tags: regex

I have been trying to match this regex to no avail. What i need to do is do a non greedy match which will match the latest number to a specific word in this case: Next:

Here is the text:

```
<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/1">Prev</a>
<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/1">1</a>
<a class="current" href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/2">2</a>
<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/3">3</a>
<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/4">4</a>
<span class="separator">...</span><a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/3029">3029</a>
<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/3030">3030</a>
<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/3">Next</a>
```

I need to find 3030 as my answer which in extend is the highest number from the passage.

What i tired to do:

```
(/d)+.*?Next
```

This however always matches (1) the first number on the 2nd line instead of the highest number 3030. It was my understanding that `.*?` does a non greedy match which should match the latest occurrence.

Can anyone help me? 
thanks 
M

Comment: You only want it to grab 3030, and not 3029 in the previous line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[\s\S]*>(\d+)<
```

You can try this.Grab the  `group 1` or `capture 1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/28

Here you do a `greedy  match` upto a `number`.So this will stop at the last occurance of number between `><`.`.` will not match newlines by default so either `DOTALL` or `[\s\S]` can be used.

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct because yours did much less steps than the other answers.  Nice explanation thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML with regexes is generally ill-advised. This website explains why and gives you better alternatives in all major languages.

You haven't specified which language you're working in, but this regex will work in most cases:

```
(\d+)(?:<[^>]+>[^<]*){2}Next
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/peNqvA244anum_v5)

The number will be in the first capture-group. Effectively I'm saying that after the number should be `{2}` instances of of `<` then any characters that aren't `>` until the `>` and optionally some characters that aren't `<` until the next instance. After those 2 instances of `<something>` should be the word `Next`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is the preferred method for parsing HTML.

```
s = """<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/1">Prev</a>
<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/1">1</a>
<a class="current" href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/2">2</a>
<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/3">3</a>
<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/4">4</a>
<span class="separator">...</span><a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/3029">3029</a>
<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/3030">3030</a>
<a href="/forum/view-forum/standard-trading-shops/page/3">Next</a>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
text = soup.text.splitlines()
index = text.index('Next')
result = text[index-1]

>>> print result
3030
```

Not as elegant as a regular expression, but it's the proper way to do it.

Comment: I understand that this is technically the correct way to do this. I tried beautiful soup but its not as quick as regex (if done in as least steps as possible). My application is very process intensive which renders this method unable to help in this case.